# Large project with Composer dependencies is constantly needing json file modification

Tags: php, dependency-management, composer-php

I have an issue/workflow in a large project with quite a number of composer packages where every so often my json file needs to be updated with a new version for a package or composer will not update. Other dependency managers in other languages would handle this type of situation on the fly (for the most part) without manual interaction. Is there a convention I am missing with Composer or a better way of doing this? It sucks time manually checking the package page online and getting all packages synced again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require a package with a flexible constraint, like `1.*` or such, then when you run `composer update` it will update you to the latest version matching this constraint. What you describe is definitely not the intended workflow so I think you have a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I have several packages which use the wildcard. Some have the version as this 2.2.*@dev. Should I only put 2.2.*? It also seems to affect things going down the chain so unsure this is really the final answer.

Comment: `2.2.*@dev` is ok, it's the same as `2.2.*` but will allow alpha/beta/RC and dev versions too.

Comment: I guess maybe I am looking for something to "freeze" the vendor area if you will so that once everything is at a stable point there are no unexpected updates. Is there a command to freeze it without a manual process of only updating one vendor at a time when needed?

Comment: Whenever you run update, the new state is written into the composer.lock file. When you run install, if there is a composer.lock present it will install that and ignore your composer.json. That's essentially your "frozen" state. And you should definitely commit this file and only run install when deploying to production/CI.

Comment: hmm I just ran into this issue when pushing my code to another environment that relies solely on the composer.json file to rebuild the vendor dependencies. "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*" is what I had put in my json file per your suggestion instead of "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev". It can't seem to find it. Am I restricted to the dev versions in a sense? What I really want is composer to be smart enough to grab the last stable build and ignore my version number if not accurate. Even if I could just pass "stable" on as the version package, that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you anymore. You can use `1.1.*@dev` to allow dev versions (always latest) or `1.1.*@alpha` for example to allow up to alpha releases. In this case, since the package has no stable 1.1 release yet, you need at least to specify `@alpha`.

Comment: Your comment about saving the composer.lock file was exactly what I needed! Thanks for sticking with this post like you did.